# Is there a functional difference between > *:first-child and > :first-child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Writing a block of code, I noticed that in one place I wrote `> :first-child` and later on `> *:first-child`. Both blocks appear to be functional, but is there a difference between the two?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: If there is any difference, I believe it is [irrelevant](https://meiert.com/en/blog/performance-of-css-selectors-2/).

Comment: So, performance-wise, they are identical. I guess it all comes down to a matter of preference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are identical even if we consider performance. From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#universal-selector) we can read

> If a universal selector represented by * (i.e. without a namespace prefix) is not the only component of a sequence of simple selectors selectors or is immediately followed by a pseudo-element, then the * **may be omitted** and the universal selector's **presence implied**.

So writing `> :first-child` should mean the same as `> *:first-child` for the browser.

You can also read

> Note: it is recommended **that the * not be omitted**, because it decreases the potential confusion between, for example, `div :first-child` and `div:first-child`. Here, `div *:first-child` is more readable.

So it's not only a matter of preference but it helps avoid confusion and make the code more readable.

---

In [the new sepcification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-universal-selector) we can also read:

> Unless an element is featureless, the presence of a universal selector **has no effect** on whether the element matches the selector.

and

> Note: In some cases, adding a universal selector can make a selector easier to read, even though it has no effect on the matching behavior. For example, `div :first-child` and `div:first-child` are somewhat difficult to tell apart at a quick glance, but writing the former as `div *:first-child` makes the difference obvious.