# Is there a way to :first-of-type::first-letter except if element has parent of a given type?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, styled-components

I have the following TypeScript React code.

```js
const Container = styled.div`
  p:first-of-type::first-letter {
    font-size: 4rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    @media only screen and (max-width: ${breakpoints.s}px) {
      font-size: 3.2rem;
      line-height: 1.6rem;
      margin-right: 0.8rem;
    }
  }
}
```

I would like `p:first-of-type::first-letter` to apply if `p` is not the child of a `blockquote`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean it shouldn't apply if `p` is a *direct* child of a `blockquote`, you can use this combination of selectors:

```
*:not(blockquote) > p:first-of-type::first-letter
```

OR, for plain CSS also (but apparently *not* working in *styled-components* - see comments):

```
:not(blockquote) > p:first-of-type::first-letter
```

(without the universal selector, which is not necessarily needed, but makes it a bit easier to understand)

The direct parent can be anything but a blockquote this way. Here's a snippet:

```css
*:not(blockquote)>p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  @media only screen and (max-width: $ {
    breakpoints.s
  }
  px) {
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    margin-right: 0.8rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Test regular paragraph tag</p>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Test paragraph tag as child of blockquote</p>
  </blockquote>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't think the wild card is needed

Comment: @Johannes the `*`

Comment: @Johannes the asterisk `*`

Comment: Ah, the universal selector. No, it's not, but it's easier to understand that way.

Comment: FYI, the `*` is necessary for my use case.

Comment: @Johannes What is the difference between with or without the `*`?

Comment: @sunknudsen none, actually. The `* `just makes it more obvious (or visible) that `:not(...)`  is combined with an element

Comment: @Johannes In the context of `const Container = styled.div`, it is actually required. Without it, the `p:first-of-type::first-letter` properties are not applied. Interesting.

Comment: that is styled-components issue, not react's.

Comment: Okay, so: ah, interesting. I was only thinking of CSS here, but obviously styled-components require a bit more.

Comment: @sunknudsen related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60493437/8620333

Answer (score 2):

**updated answer**

to avoid applying it to direct children of blockquote you could use

```
*:not(blockquote) > p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

---

**original answer**

You could create an additional rule to target when it is indeed a child of a `blockquote` and override this one.

```
blockquote p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

---

Demo

```css
blockquote p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  font-size: inherit;
}

p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<p>this is some affected &lt;p&gt; element</p>
<hr/>
<blockquote>
<p>this is not affected</p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Thanks! Updated the question. Was hoping I wouldn’t have to override all properties.

Comment: @sunknudsen is it only for direct child of `blockquote` or any level inside it ?

Comment: @sunknudsen updated answer that ignores `p` that are direct children of `blockquote`.