# Negation pseudo-class selector [:not()] not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In the following example, I’ll expect **all** `p` elements to render with a *green* background, since the *red* background should only be apply if the `.red` class is **not** a descendant of a `.green` class. Yet, this is not the case.

```css
.green p {
  background: green;
}

:not(.green) .red > p {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="green">
  <p>Neutrum vero, inquit ille. Et nemo nimium beatus est; Age, inquies, ista parva sunt. Haec para/doca illi..
    <p/>
    <div class="red">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Hoc enim constituto in philosophia constituta sunt omnia. Num quid tale Democritus..</p>
      <p>Zenonis est, inquam, hoc Stoici. Certe, nisi voluptatem tanti aestimaretis. Erat enim Polemonis. Tanta vis admonitionis inest in locis.</p>
      <p>Age sane, inquam. Omnis enim est natura diligens sui. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quid ergo attinet gloriose loqui.</p>
    </div>
    <p>Pro consul accusata id, errem nonumy assentior qui et. Quem albucius omittantur id sea, duo cu posse insolens.
      <p/>
</section>
```

Why the negation selector is not working as expected in this example?

Comment: :not(.green) will match anything so also <html> and <body>. If the second CSS rule was ":not(.green) > .red > p", all `<p>`s will have a green background.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a selector in front of the pseudo class e.g. in you case you want `section:not(.green) .red > p` a pseudo-class is a keyword added to a selector.

Comment: I tried with the universal selector `*:not(.green) .red > p` and  it does not work either. Any idea why?

Comment: @VorganHaze the universal selector is implicit when you don't add it so `:not(.green)` is the same as `*:not(.green)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/60495422/8620333

Comment: I'm not actually sure, but it looks like this answer has some more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794545/universal-selector-and-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 1):

**You need to add root selector with not.**

```css
.green p {
  background: green;
}

root:not(.green) .red > p {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="green">
  <p>Neutrum vero, inquit ille. Et nemo nimium beatus est; Age, inquies, ista parva sunt. Haec para/doca illi..
    <p/>
    <div class="red">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Hoc enim constituto in philosophia constituta sunt omnia. Num quid tale Democritus..</p>
      <p>Zenonis est, inquam, hoc Stoici. Certe, nisi voluptatem tanti aestimaretis. Erat enim Polemonis. Tanta vis admonitionis inest in locis.</p>
      <p>Age sane, inquam. Omnis enim est natura diligens sui. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quid ergo attinet gloriose loqui.</p>
    </div>
    <p>Pro consul accusata id, errem nonumy assentior qui et. Quem albucius omittantur id sea, duo cu posse insolens.
      <p/>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```