# css :not() selector not working with universal selector (*)

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Haii

Looks like the css selector `:not()` doesn't work well with the `*` selector.

Any way around it?
Or am I doing something wrong?

```css
*:not(.nope){
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>hai</div>
<div>I</div>
<div class="nope">am</div>
<div>Jhon</div>
```

I still get `'am'` as green.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that `*` isn't mandatory: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60493437/8620333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The universal selector (`*`) is not the problem. It's the inheritance on the `color` property.

When you say...

```
*:note(.nope)
```

that's fine, but you're forgetting that `*` applies the color to the `body` and `html` elements, as well.

So `.nope` gets the green from its parent.

If you use a property that is not inherited (like `border`) you won't have this problem.

```css
*:not(.nope){
  border: 1px solid red;
}

* {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>hai</div>
<div>I</div>
<div class="nope">am</div>
<div>Jhon</div>
```

Notice how `.nope` doesn't get the border.

For the color to work as you want, be more specific.

```css
div:not(.nope) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>hai</div>
<div>I</div>
<div class="nope">am</div>
<div>Jhon</div>
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks. I found that I could also do *{
  color: green;
}

.nope{
  color: blue;
}