# Difference between universal and descending selector in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am wondering if someone can tell me when to use the universal and when to use the descendant selector in css? I have looked around for a good explanation, but didn't find a good answer to the difference between those and when to use one or the other:

```
div * .test{
   color: red;
}

div .test{
   color: red;
}
```

Update for cover all scenarios:

```
div * .test{
   color: red;
}

div *.test{
   color: red;
}

div .test{
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: **Did you mean `div *.test`?**

Comment: Let's cover all.. I updated the question

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60493437/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is to use the universal selector very sparsely due to its bad impact on performance. You basically almost never use it.

The **descendant selector**, as the name suggests, targets descendants of the element preceding the descendant selector.

Please note that both selectors you show are not exactly the same.

It helps alot to read selector from right to left:

`div * .test` targets

- items that have a css class `test` (`.test`)
- which are descendants
- of **any** element `*`
- which is a descendant
- of a `div` element.

See this example:

```css
div * .test{
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="test">test</div>
</div>
```

and now compare the same with your 2nd selector:

```css
div .test{
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="test">test</div>
</div>
```

Edit: You have now broadened your question.

`*.test` and `.test` target exactly the same elements, there is no benefit in explicitly using the universal selector here, and I would consider it bad coding practice. **Implicitly** it is already part of any selector part that does not have an element selector in it:

`#foo` is identical to `*#foo`
`[foo]` is identical to `*[foo]`

Comment: so the universal does not select the direct child element?

Comment: @Franki1986 It does. But it *requires* at least one child. If there is no in-between child (like in the first example here) then it does not match. The "descendant" variant works with 0 to unlimited in-between descendants.

Comment: @Franki1986 Also, it does not limit itself to "direct children". That would be `div > *`. The `div *` is exactly like `div .test`, only with "any type of element" in place of `.test`.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, be aware in CSS, the Child combinator (`>`) indicates a direct child relationship. While the Descendant combinator ( ) will apply for direct and indirect children.

With that in mind. The selectos `div * .test` will take elements with class `test` that are children of elements children of a `div`. And, since we are using the  descendant combinator, these can be indirect children.

But, `div .test` will take elements with class `test` that are children of a `div`.

Thus,  `div .test` will select the `span` in `<div><span class="test">test</span></div>`. Yet, `div * .test` won't, because there isn't another element between the `div` and the `span`.

They both will select  the `span` in `<div><p><span class="test">test</span></div>`.  *In this case `*` matches the `p` element. Yet, it is not necessary to match it, since we are using the  descendant combinator. In this case, using `*` is giving extra work to the browser.*

Notice that `div *` and `div` aren't selecting the same elements. The `div *` selects all children of a `div`. While `div` selects all `div`.

---

By the way, as a general rule, the simpler the selector the easier it is for the browser to check it. Browser's usual implementation checks these selectors backwards (starting by matching the rightmost part). That means that for `div *`, the browser will have to check for every element on the page to see if it is inside a `div`. Thus, the shorter and more specific you can get with your selectors, the better.

For instance, if you only want elements with the class `test` that are direct children of a `div`, use `div > .test`. That way, the browser will not be climbing the DOM looking if there was a `div` containing the element.

And, of course, if you can get away with `.test`, that is even better.

---

`*.test` will take all the elements with class `test`, which is the same as `.test`.

---

As per testing your selectos, use something like `border: 1px solid black`. That would allow you to distinguish when you select an elements from when you select its parent.

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly 3 types of selector w.r.t. what you are asking.

1. **Universal**: div *: will apply CSS to all elements inside div.
2. **Immediate children**: div > .test : will apply CSS to all immediate children inside div i.e. child1 and child2.
3. **All children: div** .test: will apply CSS to all children inside div fulfilling the condition. i.e. test.

```css
/* apply to every element */
* {
  padding: 4px;
}

div.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

/* apply to every element inside parent*/
.parnet * {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

/* apply to all immediate children element with class 'child1' inside parent*/
.parnet > .child1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

/* apply to all children element with class 'test' inside parent*/
.parnet .test {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="parnet">
  Parent
  <div class="child child1">
    child 1
    <div class="test">test 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child child2">
    child 2
    <div class="test">test 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```