# Question on the relational selectors used on "Checkbox Hack" css trick

Tags: css, css-selectors

Recently, I've tried using the "checkbox hack" to be able to do cool styles on an image when clicked instead of hovered. I am a complete beginner and currently, I don't want to touch javascript. I am trying to understand how it works and I am currently having a difficulty understanding why use universal selector  on css. I understand from a stackoverflow answer ([Difference between universal and descending selector in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64641649/difference-between-universal-and-descending-selector-in-css)) that it helps to read from right to left when reading  selectors. However how is it not possible to just use the descendant selector instead of using a  universal selector (I tried only `#box:checked ~ span` but it just doesn't  work)?

```css
#box:checked ~ * span{
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="box">
<label class="label-box" for="box">
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's possible to use a descendant selector. It's just about using the selectors in the correct way by taking care of CSS Specificity rules. You can read more about CSS specificity on the web.

Also, I suggest looking over the [symbols](https://techbrij.com/css-selector-adjacent-child-sibling) used in CSS because there may be another way also to do the same.

Look over the code snippet below without the use of a universal selector.

```css
#box:checked ~ .label-box span {
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="box">
<label class="label-box" for="box">
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This has greatly helped treat my confusion.